# top menu li active when hover over submenu

Tags: css

I came across this site http://northerly.com.au/ and I am wondering how it is possible to make an top menu li active while hovering over it's submenu. In this case it seems like there is no js script to add active class. How it is done then? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, that's not the top menu li which is active when you're hovering on the sub menu. There is a sibling SPAN before submenu element, as a result of hovering to sub menu, you are also hovering the container li element.

top li has two elements:
a SPAN has top menu title
a Sub Menu

Use a CSS selector like this:

```
li:hover span {/*span is active!*/ }
```

[See a simple demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/trkaplan/utSb2/1/)

Comment: Elegant solution, So basically if you hover over any li element inside the topMenu, span can be added any css rule. Do I get it right? I tried to add more element wrapping the subMenu and it is not working. http://jsfiddle.net/PxuZt/

Comment: Change this line: 
.topMenu xxx:hover span {background-color:#cecece;}
to this:
.topMenu li:hover span {background-color:#cecece;}